# Pegar valor do Datepicker Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Eu queria pegar o valor do `data picker` no meu `component.ts` do Angular.

Segue codigo do meu `data picker`:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 form-md-line-input" style="margin-top:-95px;">
   <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Data de Expedição"
      [formControl]="serializedDate">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker ></mat-datepicker>
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Como eu faço para obter o valor deste `input`?

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode fazer assim:

```
this.seuForm.get('serializedDate').value
```